# How to expose a service ( Experssjs Api ) deployed on minikube ( 192.168.49.2 ) to be able to access it from another device in the same network?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I've created a service inside minikube (expressjs API) running on my local machine, so when I launch the service using   `minikube service wedeliverapi --url`   i can access it from my browser with   `localhost:port/api`

minikube IP : 192.168.49.2

[image]

[image]

But I also want to access that service from another device so I can use my API from a flutter mobile application, how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Could you please replace the screenshots with text?

Comment: which one? minikube service wedeliverapi --url output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **TLDR;**

*Look at **`NodePort`** or **`Ingress`** to expose a Kubernetes `minikube` service externally*.

For `minikube` specifically, there is one last networking layer between the `minikube` VM and the host. You need to enable port forwarding from the Host into the VM.  To forward [the entire default `minikube` `NodePort` range](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#increasing-the-nodeport-range):

```
for port in {30000..32767}; do VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 "NodePort$port,tcp,,$port,,$port"; done
```

To disable the port forwarding when you're done:

```
for port in {30000..32767}; do VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 delete "NodePort$port"; done
```

### Long Answer

The default `Service` type is `ClusterIP`, which only exposes the Service ***inside*** the cluster via a cluster-internal IP.

To expose a `Service` ***outside*** the `minikube` cluster, there are a few options provided by Kubernetes.

First, [we can look at `ServiceTypes`](https://v1-20.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types):

1. **`NodePort`** - Exposes a service on each cluster node at a specific port. Cluster networking routes the packets to the target `Service`'s `Pod`s.  This is the most basic way to expose a service externally.  It has existed for many years in Kubernetes.  ***This is probably the simplest way to expose a `Service`* for testing in `minikube`**.  However, if you want to do anything fancy such as TLS/SSL termination, load balacning, virtual hosts, or routing rules... use an `Ingress`.
2. `LoadBalancer` - Exposes a service using a cloud-native Load Balancer.  This is for production clusters, and probably not useful for your `minikube` use case.  It usually creates a dynamic `NodePort` for use as the cloud Load Balancer's backend target port.
3. `ExternalName` - A way to use externally hosted services through a cluster DNS `CNAME` record. Maps the service name directly to an outside DNS address, and bypasses the need for endpoint records.  *Although it's good to know this exists, this is not very useful for your use case of exposing a cluster service externally*.

Next, [we can look at port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/):

- `kubectl port-forward` command is a way to forward local traffic into a `Pod` within a Kubernetes cluster.  This feature is built into `kubectl`, and is mostly useful for local development and one-off tasks where you need to access a `Pod` directly.  This works with `Pod` names, `Deployment`s, and `ReplicaSets`.

  ```
   kubectl port-forward podname-nnnnn-xxxx $LOCALPORT:$CONTAINERPORT
  ```

This is probably the simplest method for accessing a `Pod` providing a `Service` quickly in order to test that it's working properly and accepting traffic.

Finally, [we can look at `Ingress`](https://v1-20.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) (default: `nginx`):

- `Ingress`: An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based virtual hosting.  An `Ingress Controller` usually runs inside a `Pod` in the `kube-system` namespace and provides these features which are configurable through the `Ingress` Kubernetes API object.

For `minikube`, you need to enable it as an addon:

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Follow the [`minikube` `Ingress` tutorial here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) to get started using `ingress-nginx`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but can ingress-nginx help me to expose the service outside my machine for all devices connected to the network?

Comment: Specifically for `minikube` LAN access, there is one more networking layer to be aware of:  LAN --> Host --> minikube VM.  For this, you're probably using VirtualBox and can enable the port forwarding NAT feature to route the LAN traffic to the `minikube` VM.  (See edited answer above for commands)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to have proxy for outside your machine, I can not comment due to low reputation. You can use apache or any other like HA, nginx

Comment: sorry, brother for the late reply but can you give me more details on how to setup a reverse proxy using Nginx ? like should I have to install it on my windows machine or in minikube ?

Comment: on your Windows machine

Comment: i alrady installed nginx and used this  =====>                                                                 ` server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api/;
                }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }`     in my nginx.conf but it not redirect !!

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on minikube's start `--driver` option. I was able to handle it with `--driver=none`, which requested the `cri-docker.service` to be running. Summarizing:
Preinstall cri-docker service: e.g. Ubuntu 20:

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list


sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl


wget https://github.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd/releases/download/v${VER}/cri-dockerd-${VER}.amd64.tgz
tar xvf cri-dockerd-${VER}.amd64.tgz
sudo mv cri-dockerd/cri-dockerd /usr/local/bin/
tar xvf cri-dockerd-${VER}.amd64.tgz
sudo mv cri-dockerd/cri-dockerd /usr/bin/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd/master/packaging/systemd/cri-docker.service
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd/master/packaging/systemd/cri-docker.socket
sudo mv cri-docker.socket cri-docker.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo sed -i -e 's,/usr/bin/cri-dockerd,/usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd,' /etc/systemd/system/cri-docker.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable cri-docker.service
sudo systemctl start cri-docker.socket
```

0. run your minikube, e.g. `minikube start --driver=none --container-runtime=docker`
   , also check `minikube ip`
1. deploy app - run your service
2. expose the service
3. run ingress ( as suggestet above - `minikube addons enable ingress` )
4. you should now be able to access it externally.

PS Many thanks to the post creator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726849/6571708